# SQL UPDATE over JDBC in SAP Hana is not persistent

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

We are currently migrating from Oracle to SAP Hana, and we are using Java-programs that access the database via JDBC.

When I do a SQL-update to the Hana database in Java, this change is not written to the database.

After the update, I use Squirrel to check whether the table has been changed and the change is not visible!

How can I write data with UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE in Hana via JDBC?

Comment: Impossible to tell what's wrong because you don't show any code.

Comment: Check Transactions .

Comment: Sounds as if your code doesn't `commit`

Comment: I have never used and never committed transactions with JDBC and SQL, and yet the data has always been written to the database, for different databases.
Can someone please give me a JDBC example of how I can commit in Hana using a Java program?

Comment: I just remembered something: I use the addition autocommit = false in the JDBC connection string. That is probably the culprit! Do I have to set autocommit to true or omit it entirely?

Answer (score 1):

As SipCat found out himself, this behavior is caused by

- using `autocommit=false`
- **and NOT** `COMMIT`ing the changes made by the application.

In this situation, the transaction will be rolled back when the application disconnects the DB session.

Several SQL Editor/Query UI tools (like DBSquirrel) use `autocommit=true` or automatically issue a `COMMIT` after each command, so that it may appear that there is no `COMMIT` required or that no transaction handling would be involved.

That is a false impression. In fact, even `SELECT`s (which "just" read data) technically are always in a transaction context.

Comment: This is really helpful. I was writing to Hana DB, and the data was not persistent because `autocommit` was set to false.